# Penalty weighting - optimization

Tags: r, optimization

I am new to R and optimization. I am trying to optimize the total revenues over a 5 month period of a wheat harvest that is divided in 3 areas. I want to introduce two constraints:

-At each time step I am only allowed to harvest in one area

-The area that is open has a harvest rate (HR) between 0.1 and 0.5 (while of course, the other two have a harvest rate of 0)

Hence, I want an optimization that 1. Finds the area to open and 2. Assigns a HR to it, maximizing the revenues at each time step.

So far I have been able to make it work introducing a penalty function, with a random penalty parameter. However, it only works for short time periods (for example, 5 or 10 months). When I increase the time to 15 months or longer, then two patches or three of them are opened for some of the timesteps.
How can I make sure just one patch is open per month for longer time periods?

I am pasting here a toy example. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
r=3
c=10

biomass = matrix (runif(r*c , 50, 100), r, c)

price = matrix(runif(r*c, 5, 10), r, c)

yield = matrix(NA, r, c)
revenues = yield
value = rep(NA, c)


crop = function(HR){
  
  HR = matrix(HR, r, c) 
  
  for (i in 1:c){  
  
    if (i<c){
    yield[,i] = biomass[,i] * HR[,i]
    revenues[,i] = yield[,i] * price[,i]
    biomass[,i+1] = biomass[,i] - yield[,i]
    value[i] = sum(revenues[,i])
    
    }else{
    yield[,i] = biomass[,i] * HR[,i]
    revenues[,i] = yield[,i] * price[,i]
    value[i] = sum(revenues[,i])
    output=sum(value)
    
    }
   } 
  return(output)
}



penalty <- function(HR) {  
  
  HR1 <- matrix(HR, r, c)
  
  penaltyfun = 12000 * ((HR1[1,]*HR1[3,])^2 + (HR1[1,]*HR1[2,])^2 + (HR1[2,]*HR1[3,])^2)
  
  mainfun <- crop(HR1-penaltyfun)
  
  return(mainfun)
}


HR= matrix(0.1, r, c)
test  = optim(par=as.vector(HR), fn=penalty, lower=0, upper=0.5,
              control = list(fnscale = -1),
              method = 'L-BFGS-B')

options(max.print=100000)
matrix(test$par, r, c)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the page. Could you please fix the missing matrix at the start of the code? (Most likely the HR one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is not the function you are looking for

When you are holding a hammer, everything starts looking like a nail.

From what you told us and your code you are solving this problem:

- You have a series of triples **(biomass<sub>1</sub>, biomass<sub>2</sub>, biomass<sub>3</sub>)**
- and a similar series of prices **(price<sub>1</sub>, price<sub>2</sub>, price<sub>3</sub>)**
- From these, you calculate **revenue<sub>i</sub> = biomass<sub>i</sub> * harvest_rate * price<sub>i</sub>**.
- Your goal is to maximize revenue across the whole series.

**Observation 1:** There is no reason to ever have **harvest rate** on the harvested area smaller then maximum unless you introduce some other constraint.<sup>1</sup>

**Observation 2:** Since the harvested amount has no connection to the subsequent biomass or prices, you will get the `maximum_total_revenue = sum(max_revenue(step))`

**Observation 3:** Since you can only harvest from only one field at once, you are simply looking for max(revenue<sub>1</sub>, revenue<sub>2</sub>, revenue<sub>3</sub>) and no further optimization is necessary.

**Result of observation 1, 2 & 3:** Don't use `optim`, it is an overkill. Just go over the time series, compute the maxima and add them together.

#### If you insist:

It might be, that the case you have posted is just an example to learn from. In such case, use of `optim` for might be warranted. In your case, the `optim` function maximizes the crop(HR1, HR2, HR3) - penalty(HR1, HR2, HR3).

**Observation1:** since your HRs are < 1, you are actually shooting yourself to the foot by squaring the terms since in such case `(HR1[1,]*HR1[3,])^2 < (HR1[1,]*HR1[3,])`.<sup>2</sup> Since you are trying to get the penalty as big as possible in case where more than one HR is nonzero, you likely don't want to do that.

**Observation 2:** computing the the penalty as `crop(HR1-penaltyfun)` is a bit weird. The issue is that you are suddenly computing some negative crop rates and the things kind of breaks down when trying to compute that. I'm not too sure why that happens as I don't know the insides of the `optim` too well. So I would recommend the penalty to be `crop(HR1) - penaltyfun`. It makes a bit more sense from the layman's view - we are not penalizing the crop yield & revenue by itself, we are only adding the penalty for breaking the constraints.

So the last thing we need to do is to ensure that the penalty is big enough to discourage the optimizer from harvesting two patches at once. When can this happen? 
If `H1 * H2 * penalty_constant / columns < revenue(H1) + revenue(H2)`. E.g. if the revenue for the given step is bigger when breaking the rules than when upholding them.<sup>3</sup>

How can be combat this blatant rule breaking?
By adjusting the penalty_constant. You want the constant to be big enough to warranty the **"only one harverster"** policy but not as big as to send the optimizer into panic: **"harvesting is scary, I will rather not harvest at all since the penalty is so huge"**.

```
penalty <- function(HR) {
 HR1 <- matrix(HR, r, c)      
  penaltyfun = 100 * c * ((HR1[1,]*HR1[3,]) + (HR1[1,]*HR1[2,]) + (HR1[2,]*HR1[3,]))      
  mainfun <- crop(HR1) - sum(penaltyfun)
  return(mainfun)
}
```

This one worked rather well for me. It might still need some tweaking though. Especially if you want to get the result different from the HR_max for every nonzero resulting value.

---

<sup>1</sup>Nonlinear constraint would be required - since otherwise the HR would be either 0 or 0.5 depending on whether it is worth to harvest or not.
<sup>2</sup> 0.5<sup>2</sup> = 0.25 < 0.5
<sup>3</sup> The optimizer is telling us something like: Are you sure you don't want to steal the neighbors harvester just for this one day? The reward is well worth it.